# Keeping the cache warm in a distributed web service

Tags: web-services, language-agnostic, concurrency

I've been thinking about a problem one might experience in a high load web service where many processes can handle requests, and with a central cache.

The thing is that the expiring cache entries when their values are modified in the database can have a huge performance impact. If a just-expired-entry is requested by many requests at the same time you are gonna hit the database once per each request.

You can update the cache whenever you update the database to avoid that, but now you have a race condition.

How would you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I've been in this situation myself. The solution here is not to expire the cache, but update it. When the database is updated with new content, then update the cache. Voila, no race-conditions. If the update fails ( or takes a few seconds ), your database won't be hammered with attempts to grab uncached data since it will have the old cache to fall back on. :)

**EDIT:**

To solve the issue of threads racing each other, you'll want to incorporate a [mutex lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion) of some sort. You'll naturally use something applicable to your language.

Basically, it's mutual exclusion.

You lock a portion of your logic and the other thread(s) have to wait. This avoids data corruption.

**Here's an example:**

Some thread wants to update the database:

1. Add mutex lock.
2. Update the database.
3. Update the cache.
4. Unlock the mutex.

Comment: If you update the db and then cache this could happen:
thread 1 updates the db,
thread 2 updates the db,
thread 2 updates the cache,
thread 1 updates the cache,
the cache is corrupted

Comment: Oh I see. It's the threading that's the real problem. Apologies for not grasping the full scope of your issue right off. I'll update my answer a bit.

Comment: Spencer, your edit solves the problem only if the threads can share memory (maybe they are different processes or even on different machines), and introduces another one: what if the mutex isn't acquired in a long time? do you let your user wait?

Comment: If they don't share memory, then perhaps you may consider making use of what they do share. In this case, they share a database. You can use a similar approach, but store an extra value to alert the other threads to the status of the value ( locked or unlocked ). As for your second point about letting users wait, will they need to? Will the database updates occur so often and take so long that this will be an issue?